# Adjacent sibling selector not working with dynamically added class in IE7/8

Tags: css

```
<span id='span1'>span1</span>
<span>span2</span>
<button id='btn'>select span1</button>

#span1.selected + span {
    background-color:red;
}

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#span1').addClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSGh5/

I'm using adjacent sibling selector to style checkbox with the custom image, so I don't want to abandon this selector. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is a known bug, see the section about `+` selector here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: "IE8 updates correctly, but only after you remove the focus from the test link." But [that fiddle not works in IE8 with or without focus](http://jsfiddle.net/xSGh5/), so how to fix it?

Comment: To force IE rerun style matching you could try to toggle a class on `body` for example when the button is clicked. But to minify performance issues it would be better to put the class on a parent that is as close as possible to the spans you need to style. And check if the browser is IE7/8 so that other browsers don't get penalized. See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xSGh5/4/

Comment: Great, that will fix it! I tested the fiddle in IE8 and if the `class="selected"` for the `#span1` is defined inline, it works ok, but if it's added dynamically via javascript, the DOM is [not refreshed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732329/forcing-a-dom-rerender-in-ie8) until clicked the Refresh icon in IE Developer Tools. Well, [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSGh5/6/) a bit closer to the original one. Thanks Spadar and +1 for your answer!

Comment: Beware that `$.browser` is deprecated in jQuery 1.8. And you could mark the answer as acceped)

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for the note, I missed it. They are gonna [move the browser detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) to a separated plugin, probably it's not so frequently used as other functions and it will shrink jQuery a bit. Well, so that detection can be simply removed from the fiddle, it's not so useful anyway. So basically, [that workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/xSGh5/7/) is: `$(document.body).addClass('asdfghjk').removeClass('asdfghjk');` And yes I agree, your answer can be accepted.