# Strange CSS displaying issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm managing a `<a>`'s element display with jquery. Based on some keypress events, it appends or removes an `<input>`'s class (responsible with `display` management) that has a sibling relationship with the mentioned `<a>`.

The problem is that, i have a selector that uses CSS `+`. And for some reason, in Chrome (im not sure about other browsers since i have not tested), it won't `display:block` the `<a>` element when the sibling `<a>` has the class.

### HTML

```
<div class="cont">
    <input class="myInput"/>
    <label>S</label>
    <a>X</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.cont {
    position: relative;
}
a {
    position: absolute;    
    left: 117px;
    top: 3px;
    display: none;
}
label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 3px;
}
.has_typed + label + a {
    display: block;
}
```

### Script

```
$("input").on('keyup', function(){
    var thiss = $(this);
    if (thiss.val() != 0 && !(thiss.hasClass('has_typed'))) {
        thiss.addClass('has_typed');
    }
    else if (thiss.val() == 0) {
        thiss.removeClass('has_typed');
    }
});
```

**Fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/aF4qt/1/

Comment: Always include relevant codes in question too.

Comment: There is no <span> element in your example.

Comment: thanks, changed them into anchors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
.has_typed + label + a { ... }
```

To:

```
.has_typed ~ label + a { ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/aF4qt/7/

Comment: @Mr_Green you wouldn't use that, as that would also select *any* `a` element that precedes the label. In this case that would be fine, but if OP were to add more `a` tags those would also be affected. `+` ensures that only the `a` element directly after the label is selected.

Comment: Strange fact is that, if you try to inspect the element (anchor) with my original selectors (using two 'pluses') and change the, let's say, left with +1 or -1 px, it will be displayed. Is this normal ?

Comment: @Zubzob it looks like your styling on `a` has higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `+ ... + a`, whereas `~ ... + a` has higher specificity. I'm not sure why this is, mind you.

Comment: @Zubzob on second thoughts it looks more like a (jQuery-specific?) bug than a specificity issue. If you remove the jQuery and add the class directly to the `input` to begin with, your initial `elem + elem + a` combination works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/aF4qt/10/. Odd!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly «that would also select any a element that precedes the label» did you mean: «that follows» ?

Comment: I don't understand why the + + doesn't work, since it means «select all the `a` elements placed immediatly after `label` elements placed immediatly after `.has_typed` classed elements», and your `label` element is placed immediatly after your `.has_typed` element.

Comment: @donkeydown this is a known bug. according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11936214/1577396).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing every thing in jQuery then why not do the rest using jQuery itself.

Try this:

```
$('.has_typed + label + a').show();
```

Not sure though why the same was not working in css

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aF4qt/12/)

This will also work if you have multiple groups.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aF4qt/11/)

Check this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935581/1577396)** for more info.